# call shell script from php when ubuntu 14.04 (rightly) disables the shell for www-data

Tags: command-line, 14.04, scripts, php

I just migrated from 12.04 to 14.04. 14.04 (sensibly) disables login / shell for www-data. But my php site needs to run some shell scripts to run stuff like kindlegen, rsyncing files to another server at user command etc.

Whats the best (most secure) way to do this?

thanks

Comment: That login is disabled shouldn't prevent scripts from being run when called by php code, as long as correct permissions are set for any files being accessed. Are you facing a problem running a script?

Comment: How do you want to run these scripts ? From within the PHP application, fired by some interaction with the users via the web browser or via the crontab of the web server ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're in safe mode. That's fine but it does give you the option of allowing certain commands if they're defined in [`safe_mode_exec_dir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode-exec-dir). That would be the first thing I looked at. Create a directory, add your script in there, set `safe_mode_exec_dir` to that directory and see if it runs.

<sup>Edit: Hmm, if you're on 14.04 it's probably not safe mode. That was removed in 5.4 and you should be on 5.5</sup>

If that doesn't work or isn't feasible, consider a non-interactive method. Have your PHP write to a file called `needstorun` and then have another script (running as another user) check that file on a regular basis. I'd use a cron line like this (run `crontab -e` as the user it's going to run as)

```
*/5 * * * *    [ -f /path/to/needstorun ] && rm /path/to/needstorun && /path/to/script
```

That's obviously only going to offer you a staggered approach but that might not be a bad idea.

Comment: yes. not in safe mode. yes its php5.5. /etc/password has /usr/sbin/nologin as the shell. They have done The Right Thing (grin).